# How do I clear cache on KakaoTalk, on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I use KakaoTalk on my iPhone. On [Mar 31 2015](https://twitter.com/kakaotalk/status/582867893106319360), @kakaotalk tweeted

> Hi @ZephPhillips you can clear up space by going to your KakaoTalk settings and clearing the cache. Hope that helps~

But I found no option to clear cache in KakaoTalk settings on my iPhone. Can someone please list all steps and screenshot them?

I contacted KakaoTalk by completing their online form, but they haven't replied.